# Picking all records from a table that match smallest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a few hundred records. Let's say, for simplicity, that it has only two fields (`ID` and `DateModified`).

I need to get all records that match the smallest `DateModified` value in the table.

For example, I have 6 records (`ID / DateModified`):

```
ID    DateModified
344   11-June-2011
345    5-June-2011
346    5-June-2011
347   20-June-2011
348    5-June-2011
349   16-June-2011
```

The query should return records 345, 346 and 348. How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table  
WHERE  DateModifiedvalue = (SELECT min(DateModifiedvalue) 
                            FROM table1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 with ties *
from YourTable
order by DateModified
```